# Setting up a WingIDE environment for python scripting for MCEdit

Tags: python, wing-ide

Brand new to WingIDE and have limited python experience.

How can I set up a WingIDE project so I can create MCEDIT filters?

https://github.com/mcedit/mcedit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MCEdit from sources you can probably set up a Wing project with mcedit.py as the main debug file and just debug the whole thing, then you'll be able to set breakpoints, etc also in filters.

Alternatively, you could copy wingdbstub.py from your Wing installation into the same directory as the filters and add 'import wingdbstub' to start debugging when the filter is run.  You will need to click on the bug in lower left of Wing's main window to Enable Passive Listen (or "Accept Debug Connections" in Wing 5+).  You may want to set kEmbedded=True in wingdbstub.py (if Wing drops the debug connection after the filter is used once, this indicates the filters are invoked in a way that requires this flag to be set).  If you still run into problems w/ dropped debugger connections then also call wingdbstub.Ensure() just after the import.  You may also need to set WINGHOME in your copy of wingdbstub.py (depends on how you installed; this is set up automatically in most cases).   This is all documented in more detail at https://wingware.com/doc/debug/debugging-externally-launched-code

If you're new to Wing you may want to go through the Tutorial in the Help menu first.  We don't have documentation specific to setting up Wing for MCEdit but some of the How-Tos for rendering and composting systems at https://wingware.com/doc/howtos may be useful to look at since they probably invoke their Python code in a way similar to MCEdit's filters mechanism.

If you have trouble with this please email support at wingware dot com and/or post comments here.